# Okhttp3 token change with each request get

Tags: android, spring-boot, spring-security, okhttp

I am trying to make a login from android using the library Okhttp3, but I can not keep the csrf token without it changing.
I tried to get the header "X-CSRF-TOKEN" but I can not get it, I turned to the Jsoup library to parse the html and filter the _csrf to make the post request but the csrk token changes.
I am using Spring boot + spring security, running on localhost.
I need help because I search google and I have not found a solution.

```
<form class="col s12" id="formlogin" action="#" th:action="@{/logincheck}"      th:method="POST">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="validate" th:required="required"/>
                    <label for="usuario">username</label>
            </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">lock</i>
                    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="validate" th:required="required"/>
                    <label for="password">password</label>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light pink col s12 m4 l4 xl4 right " type="submit"
                            name="action">
                            sign in
                            <i class="material-icons left">send</i>
                    </button>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Android Code:

```
final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/login";

    final OkHttpClient client;
    client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url)
            .build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);

    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            String html = response.body().string();
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
            String token = doc.select("input[name=_csrf]").val();
            Log.e("token", token);
            final RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("username", "username")
                    .add("password", "password")
                    .add("_csrf",token)
                    .build();

            String urlpost = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/logincheck";
            Request request2 = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url).post(formBody).build();


            Call call2 = client.newCall(request2);

            call2.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    Log.e("body", response.body().string());
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

Spring boot response with:

```
{"timestamp":1532156617366,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.","path":"/logincheck"}
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.
```

The problem is with your session, you need to save your spring security cookie session, here is an exemple of handle all cookies.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cookieJar(new CookieJar() {
                    private final HashMap<String, List<Cookie>> cookieStore = new HashMap<>();

                    @Override
                    public void saveFromResponse(@NonNull HttpUrl url, @NonNull List<Cookie> cookies) {
                        cookieStore.put(url.host(), cookies);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(@NonNull HttpUrl url) {
                        List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.get(url.host());
                        return cookies != null ? cookies : new ArrayList<Cookie>();
                    }
                })
                .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do I continue with what you have shared? I have activated the csrf, the app is used by normal users through the browser and also on android, thank you very much.

Comment: You set the .cookieJar on your client field, istead of  client = new OkHttpClient(), you can put my code.

Comment: After using your code, I continued using: final RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder().add("username", "username")
                    .add("password", "password")
                    .add("_csrf",token)
                    .build();

            String urlpost = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/logincheck";
            Request request2 = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url).post(formBody).build();

            Call call2 = client.newCall(request2);
            call2.enq....        But I got the same result. Do you think I should deactivate the csrf? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try setting a HEADER in your request "X-CSRF-Token" with the token